# Which gives better performance: WCF RIA services or Domain Services?

Tags: wcf, service, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I am building a new SV application which will be used from the Internet. I am expecting to
have a few users at a time, so I will need good performance.

Which is better to use:

- build from 0 WCF RIA services or
- use Domain Services?

On WCF RIA I can set up a service behavior for ConcurrencyMode but for Domain Service I couldn't find any info about that.

Also I am a little new to this so be gentle :).

Comment: DomainService is part of WCF RIA Services :)